# How to select group's rows having the greatest index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` as bellow (much bigger), I have `groupby` 'A' and I want to select the row of each group (foo and bar) with the `greatest index`.

```
serie2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['foo','foo','foo','bar','bar','bar'],'a':   [1,2,5,3,6,4],'b':np.random.rand(6)})
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**timing:** for 1.2M rows DF:

```
In [60]: a.shape
Out[60]: (1200000, 3)

In [61]: %timeit a.loc[a.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].max()]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop
```

**Conclusion:** it takes 1.25 second on my home notebook for 1.200.000 rows DF

**UPDATE:**

```
In [47]: a = a.loc[a.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].max()]

In [48]: a
Out[48]:
     A  a         b
5  bar  4  0.365713
2  foo  5  0.291325
```

Explanation:

we use `reset_index()` in order to preserver index values after the `groupby` call, but it won't reset index in the original DF, it'll be done on the DF's copy:

```
In [46]: a.reset_index()
Out[46]:
   index    A  a         b
0      0  foo  1  0.079306
1      1  foo  2  0.714666
2      2  foo  5  0.291325
3      3  bar  3  0.554277
4      4  bar  6  0.827812
5      5  bar  4  0.365713
```

**OLD answer:**

is that what you want?

```
In [23]: a
Out[23]:
     A  a         b
0  foo  1  0.079306
1  foo  2  0.714666
2  foo  5  0.291325
3  bar  3  0.554277
4  bar  6  0.827812
5  bar  4  0.365713

In [24]: a.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].max()
Out[24]:
A
bar    5
foo    2
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

or:

```
In [25]: idx = a.reset_index().groupby('A')['index'].max()

In [26]: idx
Out[26]:
A
bar    5
foo    2
Name: index, dtype: int64

In [28]: a.loc[idx]
Out[28]:
     A  a         b
5  bar  4  0.365713
2  foo  5  0.291325
```

Comment: Nop. let's say I have the exact dataframe 'a' with the index as it is it. What I need is to keep the entire rows with index 2 and 5 and drop the other rows. With my dataframe I don't want to reset the index, I need the index to select the rows.

Comment: Why do you reset_index()?

Comment: Oh yes I have tried it, it does select the index as I want but the .loc seems take ages to compute. it is still going....

Comment: @NathalieHB, usually `loc` is __very__ fast, so i think it's something else what makes it slow. In this particular case you can try `iloc` instead - it might be bit faster. What is the shape (`df.shape`) of your DF?

Comment: the shape of df is 962236-11

Comment: I think my problem is that I do not have unique indexes - When I concat my dataframes that are from read_csv files, I believe for each file, the index is re-started, which mean in on group I can have multiple time the same index (not good)- I have to make my indexes unique...

Comment: @NathalieHB, just use `pd.concat(..., ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I was looking at this ----you are so quick mate! Thanks Max!